# Is current_timestamp() evaluated at compilation or during execution in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has a current timestamp function: https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/current_timestamp

Is it evaluated during snowflake's compilation phase? or its execution phase? Asking because these times can differ by quite a lot, depending on queue time and execution time

Comment: The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function in Snowflake is evaluated during the execution phase, not the compilation phase. Snowflake docs don't explicitly state when CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is evaluated, but it does mention that it should not be used for precise time ordering between concurrent queries because the queries might be serviced by different compute resources in the warehouse which implies that the function is evaluated during the execution phase.

Comment: It depends where you use the function, for example in Snowpipe it's evaluated when the load operation is compiled in cloud services rather than when the record is inserted into the table, which can cause a difference in time. You can read about this [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-ts#load-times-inserted-using-current-timestamp-earlier-than-load-time-values-in-copy-history-view)